# Where can I find "all Rouge options"?

Tags: jekyll, kramdown, rouge

I am using Jekyll to create a static website.
I want to use `_config.yml` to configure rouge in kramdown.

After looking through the documentation for [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/) and [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax_highlighter/rouge.html), I found that it mentions

> Furthermore all Rouge options (e.g. ‘line_numbers’) can be set directly on the ‘syntax_highlighter_opts’ option (where they apply to code spans and code blocks) and/or on the ‘span’/’block’ keys.

But I can't find where the **"all Rouge options"** are.
Where can I find **"all Rouge options"**?

Comment: https://rouge-ruby.github.io/docs/#Jekyll

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax_highlighter/rouge.html) is what you are looking for?

> The Rouge syntax highlighter supports the following keys of the option
> ‘syntax_highlighter_opts’:
>
> default_lang The default language that should be used when no language
> is set. guess_lang If no specific language or a default language is
> set, guess the language. formatter A custom Rouge formatter class that
> should be used instead of the following default formatter (Rogue 1.x:
> Rouge::Formatters::HTML / Rogue 2.x: Rouge::Formatters::HTMLLegacy).
> If this setting is a string, it needs to contain the name of a
> constant under the Rouge::Formatters namespace.
>
> Note: The formatter class needs to respond to ::new(opts), where opts
> is a hash of options, and to #format which needs to return the HTML
> formatted source code.
>
> disable If set to true, highlighting with Rouge will be disabled.
> Should probably not be set globally but inside the ‘span’ or ‘block’
> options.
>
> span A key-value map of options that are only used when syntax
> highlighting code spans. block A key-value map of options that are
> only used when syntax highlighting code blocks. Furthermore all Rouge
> options (e.g. ‘line_numbers’) can be set directly on the
> ‘syntax_highlighter_opts’ option (where they apply to code spans and
> code blocks) and/or on the ‘span’/’block’ keys.